# How to automatically increment checkbox id in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using this code to get all data from database and display it in a table:

```
class Product
{
private $conn;
private $id;
private $name;
private $description;
private $price;
private $category_id;
private $category_name;
private $created;

public function __construct($db)
{
    $this->conn = $db;
}

public function readAll()
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT name, description, price, CategoryID, created FROM products');
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "<table class=\"highlight responsive-table\">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field=\"empty\"> </th>
                <th data-field=\"name\">Name</th>
                <th data-field=\"description\">Description</th>
                <th data-field=\"price\">Price</th>
                <th data-field=\"category\">Category</th>
                <th data-field=\"action\">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>";

    while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $n = $result['name'];
        $d = $result['description'];
        $p = $result['price'];
        $ca = $result['CategoryID'];
        $c = $result['created'];

        echo "<tbody>
                 <tr>
                 <td style=\"width:10%;\">

                            <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox\" />
                            <label for=\"checkbox\"></label>

                    </td>



                    <td style=\"width:15%;\">" .$n. "</td>
                    <td style=\"width:30%;\">" . $d. "</td>
                    <td style=\"width:10%;\">" ."$".$p. "</td>
                    <td style=\"width:15%;\">" . $ca. "</td>
                    <td style=\"width:20%;\"> 
                        <a class=\"waves-effect waves-light btn\"><i class=\"material-icons\">mode_edit</i></a>
                        <a class=\"waves-effect waves-light btn\"><i class=\"material-icons\">delete</i></a>
                    </td>";

    }

    echo "</tbody> </table>";


}
}
```

It's working, but in the 1st column I want to have a checkbox so I can mark records I want to delete / edit, but for now, whichever checkbox I click, only the 1st one get checked. How can I automatically increment checkbox id?

Comment: You should select the ID from the Db element. The ID you can use as identifying for checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the id field from the products table.  If it doesn't have one, I would add it.

Then in your html change the checkbox line to:

```
<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox".$id."\" name=\"delete_product\" value=\"".$id".\" />
<label for=\"checkbox".$id."\"></label>
```

I added name and value in case you are submitting the form, you can get that data in the POST if you end up using a form.

Comment: I used your code, and also added `$id = $result['id'];` in while  and "id" here: `$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT id, name, description, price, CategoryID, created FROM products');` but it's still not getting checked after I click checkbox

Comment: Did you check that the html is rendering as you would expect?  I suspect some possible Javascript issue if the checkbox literally won't check.  Could you explain in more detail what you might mean it's "still not getting checked."

Comment: I changed it a little bit: `<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox".$id."\" name=\"checkbox".$id."\" />
                            <label for=\"checkbox".$id."\"></label>` and now it's working, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

use a variable $i,  initialize it with 1 before while loop and
inside your loop,increment it
replace your checkbox code like

```
                        <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox_$i\" />
                        <label for=\"checkbox_$i\"></label>
```

$i++;

Answer (score 1):

Try using a counting variable like this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $n = $result['name'];
        $d = $result['description'];
        $p = $result['price'];
        $ca = $result['CategoryID'];
        $c = $result['created'];

        echo "<tbody>
                 <tr>
                 <td style=\"width:10%;\">

                            <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox".$i."\" />
                            <label for=\"checkbox".$i."\"></label>

                    </td>



                    <td style=\"width:15%;\">" .$n. "</td>
                    <td style=\"width:30%;\">" . $d. "</td>
                    <td style=\"width:10%;\">" ."$".$p. "</td>
                    <td style=\"width:15%;\">" . $ca. "</td>
                    <td style=\"width:20%;\"> 
                        <a class=\"waves-effect waves-light btn\"><i class=\"material-icons\">mode_edit</i></a>
                        <a class=\"waves-effect waves-light btn\"><i class=\"material-icons\">delete</i></a>
                    </td>";
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: Now none of them gets checked

Comment: Of course I forgot to use the same principle for the label. Check my updated answer. But to be honest I like Nikolai Engel's approach even more. If possible you should try his suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Add id column to your sql query. Then modify your first column in table to

```
<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox\" . $result['id'] . " name=\"id[" . $result['id'] . "]\"/>
<label for=\"checkbox" . $result['id'] . "\"></label>
```

In Controller you will have access to selected ids using for example $_POST['id']

Comment: Incorrect escaping happening here, which is likely to happen with this sort of quoting approach.  I might look into using single quote wrapper so you can freely use double quotes in the html.